# MS ACCESS Lock a table during update, blocking

Tags: sql, ms-access, locking, blocking

How can I lock a table preventing other users querying it while I update its contents?

Currently my data is updated by wiping the table and re-populating it (i know, its not the best way to update data, but the source data has no unique key to do a record by record update and this is the only way). There exists the unlikely, but possible scenario where a user my access the table in the middle of the update and catch it while it is empty thus returning bad info.

Is there at the SQL (or code) level a way to create a blocking statement that will wait for a DB update to complete prior to querying?

Answer (score 1):

Access has very little locking capabilities. Unless you're storing your data in a different backend, you only can set a database-wide lock or no lock at all.

There is some locking capability setting table locks when the table structure of a table is being changed, but as far as I can find, that's not available to the user (neither through the GUI nor through VBA)

Note that both ADO and DAO support locking (in ADO by setting the `IsolationLevel`, in DAO by setting `dbDenyRead + dbDenyWrite` when executing the query), but in my short testing, these options do absolutely nothing in Access.

Comment: That seems to be what my own digging has turned up as well. For now I am implementing a field that locks the record or table, but this is not bulletproof. I seem to remember researching this a year ago and finding there was an SQL statement where if you did all your queries in SQL could implement locking moderately successfully, but I have been unable to find this again.

Comment: @Wobbles You can use transactions, though, if you're looking to execute multiple statements in succession

Comment: Im looking to do this across multiple users, do transaction locks share across multiple sessions/users?

Comment: Transactions don't lock, they make sure all changes are commited simultaneously. E.g. you can delete a table, then recreate it, and then create derived tables, and this is all commited at one time, users never miss the table, and users can't edit the recreated table before the derived tables are created.

Comment: Hmm, this may be useful then, but how does the system ensure that the transaction happen at the same time without locking, what prevents a user from coming in between the period wen my table is wiped (I dont drop it I just delete records to preserve structure) and when it is repopulated? Currently users see #Deleted if they access my data during this brief period.

Comment: You can read into transactions. As far as I know, in the implementation Access uses, changes from users to deleted records are removed when the transaction is committed. I honestly don't know what happens to records created between the time the transaction is started and committed, that's something you will have to try for yourself.